# Continuous at two points, differentiable at one

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Give an example of a function which is
>
> continuous at exactly two points
>
> & differentiable at only one of them

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2(x-1) & x\in\mathbb Q\\0 & x\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q\end{cases}$$

Differentiable only in $x=0$, continuous in $x=0$ and $x=1$.

Comment: How do i prove continuity & differentiability in closed interval?

Comment: There was no 'closed interval' in your question. My example is a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. Also, in your question you did not show any of your attempts to solve this problem (a common reason for downvote), so I thought to leave a hint as an answer - please try to follow that hint and use what you know about continuity (and differentiability), and then let us know where you've got stuck. Try to sketch the graph of the function $f$ above, for example, and see that at $x=0$ it actually has something like a tangent. What does it look like at $x=1$?

Comment: How do I come up with such a function? Is there any trick to define function like that? Please explain

Comment: It's a standard trick to prevent continuity. You must have heard of Dirichlet's function: $f(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x\in\mathbb Q\\0 & x\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q\end{cases}$ which is not continuous anywhere (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function#Dirichlet_function).

Comment: What is $Q$ & $R/Q$?

Comment: $\mathbb Q$: the set of all rational numbers. $\mathbb R$: the set of all real numbers. $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$: the set of all numbers in $\mathbb R$ that are not in $\mathbb Q$, i.e. the set of all irrational real numbers.

Comment: Wow! You know so much. Thanks!